# Splitting a string with delimiters and conditions

Tags: python, regex, string, split, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to split a general string of chemical reactions delimited by `whitespace, +, =` where there may be an arbitrary number of whitespaces. This is the general case but I also need it to split conditionally on the parentheses characters `()` when there is a `+` found inside the `()`.

For example:

```
    reaction= 'C5H6 + O = NC4H5 + CO + H'
```

Should be split such that the result is

```
     splitresult=['C5H6','O','NC4H5','CO','H']
```

This case seems simple when using `filter(None,re.split('[\s+=]',reaction))`. But now comes the conditional splitting. Some reactions will have a `(+M)` which I'd also like to split off of as well leaving only the `M`. In this case, there will always be a `+M` inside the parentheses

For example:

```
    reaction='C5H5 + H (+M)= C5H6 (+M)'
    splitresult=['C5H5','H','M','C5H6','M']
```

However, there will be some cases where the parentheses will not be delimiters. In these cases, there will not be a `+M` but something else that doesn't matter.

For example:

```
    reaction='C5H5 + HO2 = C5H5O(2,4) + OH'
    splitresult=['C5H5','HO2','C5H5O(2,4)','OH']
```

My best guess is to use negative lookahead and lookbehind to match the `+M` but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the regex expression I used above on the simple case. My intuition is to use something like `filter(None,re.split('[(?<=M)\)\((?=\+)=+\s]',reaction))`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **re.findall()** instead:

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0) 
>   Return all non-overlapping
>   matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is
>   scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If
>   one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the
>   beginning of another match.

then:

```
import re
reaction0= 'C5H6 + O = NC4H5 + CO + H'
reaction1='C5H5 + H (+M)= C5H6 (+M)'
reaction2='C5H5 + HO2 = C5H5O(2,4) + OH'
re.findall('[A-Z0-9]+(?:\([1-9],[1-9]\))?',reaction0)
re.findall('[A-Z0-9]+(?:\([1-9],[1-9]\))?',reaction1)
re.findall('[A-Z0-9]+(?:\([1-9],[1-9]\))?',reaction2)
```

but, if you prefer **re.split()** and **filter()**, then:

```
import re
reaction0= 'C5H6 + O = NC4H5 + CO + H'
reaction1='C5H5 + H (+M)= C5H6 (+M)'
reaction2='C5H5 + HO2 = C5H5O(2,4) + OH'
filter(None , re.split('(?<!,[1-9])[\s+=()]+(?![1-9,])',reaction0))
filter(None , re.split('(?<!,[1-9])[\s+=()]+(?![1-9,])',reaction1))
filter(None , re.split('(?<!,[1-9])[\s+=()]+(?![1-9,])',reaction2))
```

---

the pattern for **findall** is different from the pattern for **split**,
because **findall** and **split** are looking for different things; *'the opposite things'*, indeed.

**findall**, is looking for that you wanna (keep it).

**split**, is looking for that you don't wanna (get rid of it).

In **findall**, '**[A-Z0-9]+(?:([1-9],[1-9]))?**' 
*match any upper case or number* > **[A-Z0-9]**,
*one or more times* > **+**, *follow by a pair of numbers, with a comma in the middle, inside of parenthesis* > **\([1-9],[1-9]\)**
(literal parenthesis outside of character classes, must be escaped with backslashes '\'), *optionally* > **?**

**\([1-9],[1-9]\)** is inside of **(?: )**, and then,
the **?** (which make it optional); **( )**, instead of **(?: )** works, but, in this case, **(?: )** is better; **(?: )** is a no capturing group: read about this.

try it with the regex in the **split**

Comment: There is no inherent reason for me to use `findall` over `split`. That's just what came to mind first. I'm not very familiar with regex, could you elaborate on what your pattern is matching (how it's catching the `()`) and why the pattern is different when using `findall` over `split`?

Comment: take a look at the answer now

Answer (score 0):

That seems overly complicated to handle with a single regular expression to split the string. It'd be much easier to handle the special case of (+M) separately:

```
halfway = re.sub("\(\+M\)", "M", reaction)
result = filter(None, re.split('[\s+=]', halfway))
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is the regex which you are looking for.

**Regex:** `((?=\(\+)\()|[\s+=]|((?<=M)\))`

**Flags used:**

- `g` for global search. Or use them as per your situation.

**Explanation:**

- `((?=\(\+)\()` checks for a `(` which is present if `(+` is present. This covers the first part of your `(+M)` problem.
- `((?<=M)\))` checks for a `)` which is present if `M` is preceded by `)`. This covers the second part of your `(+M)` problem.
- `[\s+=]` checks for all the remaining `whitespaces`, `+` and `=`. This covers the last part of your problem.

**Note:** The care for `digits` being enclosed by `()` ensured by both `positive lookahead` and `positive lookbehind` assertions.

<kbd>**[Check Regex101 demo for working](https://regex101.com/r/yU7uJ4/3)**</kbd>

**P.S: Make it suitable for yourself as I am not a python programmer yet.**

Comment: The problem with your regex as I understand it is the `|` operator. I believe it is _non-greedy_, meaning that it will match only one of the patterns then quit. I need it to examine the whole string and match on every instance of the pattern rather than just one.

Comment: I have used global search mode `g`. Which will find every pattern even though they are separated by `|` before quitting.